# How does OFDMA collaborate with CSMA/CA in WiFi 6 and beyond?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, 802.11

The use of CSMA in legacy WiFi conflicts with OFDMA in emerging WiFi protocols. We assume a scenario where all devices (APs and stations) are 802.11ax-based and support OFDMA. We are considering the scheduled data transmission phase, where multiple stations are allowed to transmit simultaneously but on different resource units (RUs). If stations perform carrier sensing before transmitting, they will detect that other stations are about to transmit, causing them to remain silent. In this case, only one user will transmit at a specific time, while other RUs go to waste. **The main reason for this is that carrier sensing is conducted across the entire bandwidth rather than on a single RU.**

Therefore, my questions are as follows:

With CSMA/CA, only one station is allowed to transmit at a specific time. Therefore, even though OFDMA allocates RUs for multiple stations, only the station successfully occupying the channel will transmit.

If all the stations support OFDMA, CSMA is not actually an essential function. According to some documents of 802.11ax, even in the uplink OFDMA random access (UORA) phase, CSMA is not required. The primary reason for CSMA still existing is to ensure compatibility with legacy WiFi devices. **Consequently, if there is one legacy WiFi device in the network, OFDMA will be useless, and the performance of the entire network will be bottlenecked by the performance of WiFi 4.**

Are the above thoughts correct?